# Async checkbox on Google Chrome dev tools missing

Tags: google-chrome, asynchronous, promise, google-chrome-devtools

Can't find this checkbox in new versions of Chrome. Can anyone give a hint where it's gone?

[image: async checkbox]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's been removed and async stack traces are on by default now.  Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/05/devtools-release-notes#async-stacks